# Using the PL/SQL Function body returning SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am working with Oracle APEX and I'm trying to store a dynamic sql query in the PL/SQL Function body. Here is my current SQL query for a classic report:

```
SELECT 
    RELEASE,
    COUNT(*) as "Total Tests", --total
    SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'P1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "P1",
    SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'P2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "P2",
    SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'P3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "P3",
    SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'P4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "P4"
    FROM TABLENAME
group by RELEASE
ORDER BY case
    when RELEASE = '19.3' then 1
    when RELEASE = '18.11' then 2
    when RELEASE = '18.9' then 3
    when RELEASE = '18.7' then 4
    when RELEASE = '17.3' then 5
    else 6
end asc
```

I am trying to store the 'tablename' in a page item so that whenever a user changes the page item, this query will automatically pull from the given table. I've attempted to build a pl/sql function around this but continue to run into errors with the 'strings'.

Does anyone know how to convert this in to a dynamic pl/sql function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error mesage?

Comment: ORA-20999: Parsing returned query results in "ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query! <p>ORA-06550: line 24, column 8: ORA-00904: "18.7": invalid identifier</p>".

Comment: Can you present your code for the PL/SQL Function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should

- create a classic report whose source is a function that returns a query
- that query should look like this:

  ```
  return '
    SELECT 
      RELEASE,
      COUNT(*) as "Total Tests", --total
      SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = ''P1'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "P1",
      SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = ''P2'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "P2",
      SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = ''P3'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "P3",
      SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = ''P4'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "P4"
      FROM ' || 
      SYS.DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name(:P1_TABLE_NAME) ||
    ' group by RELEASE 
    ORDER BY case
      when RELEASE = ''19.3''  then 1
      when RELEASE = ''18.11'' then 2
      when RELEASE = ''18.9''  then 3
      when RELEASE = ''18.7''  then 4
      when RELEASE = ''17.3''  then 5
      else 6
    end asc';
  ```
- `DBMS_ASSERT` is here to prevent SQL Injection
- set "use generic column names" to "Yes"
- page item's name is `:P1_TABLE_NAME` (in my example); it should be a text field, submit when press Enter

That's all, I presume.

Comment: Thank you, this works! Thanks for the DMBS_ASSERT tip as well. :)